# Replace overpunched values

Tags: pandas

I have a column(DS) in the dataframe(df_Type4) which has overpunched values like below

```
16       100
17       10}
18       20}
21       200
22       10N
```

I want to replace the last bit of it say } with 0 so that the number is 100, like wise N with 5 and so that number is 105 and so on.

I have tried to extract the last bit as below.

`df_Type4['DS'].str[2]`

I want to use if-else as there are multiple values.But however, it doesn't seem to work when I consider it as string. Any other way ?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52580093/9534390

Comment: What is the logic exactly, since you say "and so on". Why is `}` replaced by `0` and `N` by `5`. Is there some kind of pattern?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make multiple transformations, use the following:

```
trans_dict = {'}': '0',
              'N': '5'}
trans_table = ''.join(trans_dict.keys()).maketrans(trans_dict)
df_Type4['DS'] = df_Type4['DS'].str.translate(trans_table)

16  100
17  100
18  200
21  200
22  105
```

Or simpler, you can use:

```
df_Type4['DS'] = df_Type4['DS'].replace(trans_dict, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_Type4['DS'] = df_Type4['DS'].str.replace("}", "0")
df_Type4['DS'] = df_Type4['DS'].str.replace("N", "5")
# etc.
```

or chain these into one long expression:

```
df_Type4['DS'] = df_Type4['DS'].str.replace("}", "0").replace("N", "5")
```

Depending on how many different values you have that you want to replace. Then convert the column from strings to integers (or floats):

```
df_Type4['DS'] = pd.to_numeric(df_Type4['DS'])
```